# Pygame webcam streaming client can't execute with python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, video-streaming

I'm using pygame and python3.4 for stream a webcam in a Odroid board. The server is this (extracted of this post: [using pygame to stream over sockets in python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923840/using-pygame-to-stream-over-sockets-in-python-error) ):

```
import socket
import pygame
import pygame.camera
import sys
import time

port = 5000
pygame.init()

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(("",port))
serversocket.listen(1)

pygame.camera.init()
webcam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video1",(320,240))
webcam.start()

while True:
        connection, address = serversocket.accept()
        image = webcam.get_image() # capture image
        data = pygame.image.tostring(image,"RGB") # convert captured image to string, use RGB color scheme
        connection.sendall(data)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        connection.close()
```

The server works Ok in python and python 3.4.
But when I execute the client  with python 3.4 I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "client.py", line 30, in 
>       image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB") # convert received image from string
>   TypeError: must be bytes, not str

The client is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import pygame
import sys



host = "192.168.45.103"
port=5000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240),0)


while True:
    clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientsocket.connect((host, port))
    received = []
    # loop .recv, it returns empty string when done, then transmitted data is completely received
    while True:
        #print("esperando receber dado")
        recvd_data = clientsocket.recv(230400)
        if not recvd_data:
            break
        else:
            received.append(recvd_data)

    #dataset = ''.join(received)
    dataset = ','.join(str(v) for v in received)
    image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB") # convert received image from string
    screen.blit(image,(0,0)) # "show image" on the screen
    pygame.display.update()

    # check for quit events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

I changed the line dataset = ''.join(received) for dataset = ','.join(str(v) for v in received) because I read somwhere that in python3.x it mst be this. 
The error line now is: image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 lines appear to be plain wrong:

```
dataset = ','.join(received)
image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB") # convert received
```

If `dataset` is to contain the binary pxel data, you should not be concatenating the bytes you receive with ",": it would simply add a lost of extraneous "," (decimal 44) bytes as garbage in your pixel data - the previous line, using "join" with an empty string would work (in Python 2.x) becuase called upon an empty string, join simply concatenates the various piece of data, which is what you want.

In Python3, handling of binary data (such as the pixel data you are receiving) has been separated from text handling - and the '""' empty string you where using is an object representing empty text - which is different from empty bytes from Python 2.x - but you can simply prefix it with a `b` for denoting a bytes-string (which is what you want).

All in all, try just using:

```
dataset = b''.join(str(v) for v in received)
image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB")
```

Comment: Ok, now the error is:  sequence item 0: expected bytes, bytearray, or an object with the buffer interface, str found . So the problem persists

Comment: Ah, sorry, in my eager to post the corrected answer, I copied you line and fixed it in only one of two places. The `str` call on "v"  have to be removed as well, of course. Fixed above.